# How VS code run specific line on debugger mode?

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code

How to move the debuggers yellow arrow to where my orange arrow is pointing.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRFQH.png]

Comment: You can't just drag the current line that's executing. You that your thinking about the debugger wrong. The debugger is showing you what line has executed. If the debugger is not stopping on the if statement above, its how your code is executing. Once you have passed the line you can't step backwards.

Comment: Think about it like this. At any given time your program has a **state** that it is in. Not only to variables values change in a given state, but there location in memory may change as well, there types change, and scopes change. Code that has already executed has a good chance of already been being GC. It just doesn't make sense to be able to go backwards.

Comment: My suggestion to you, is to put that code into a loop, so it executes several times. That is, of course, if it is possible to do so. Usually I can get some block that I need to debug into a loop if I need to see it execute several times to try and troubleshoot WTH is going on. You won't go backwards, but you can finish out the current loops index (or interval) and loop back around so that the debugger moves back to the upper if statment.

Comment: @jD3V You can, in fact do exactly this in most languages with Visual Studio (I do it all the time with VS for VB.Net and C#) so this is an entirely reasonable question.  For some reason it appears that  cannot do it with VSCode in Javascript.  I do not know if this is a limitation of VSCode or of Javascript specifically, of if the option is hidden somewhere (I am still looking...).

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46486187/109122) it *can* be done with VSCode for C#, so it looks like it may be a Javascript limitation.  However, it was a brand new feature as of Dec 2019, so you may just need the latest version of VSCode

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hmm, according to [this article](https://adtmag.com/articles/2020/07/15/vs-code-javascript-debugger.aspx) it specifically does work for JS on VSCode as of v1.47, but I cannot find in my installation even though I am running v1.53.

Comment: @jD3V The specific line debugger can be done in Visual Studio (I use that way to trace code when C#, Python, VB.Net., etc.), but on VScode with java script seems not work at all.

Comment: Well, as near as I can figure, this feature **is** implemented by the VSCode IDE interface, but it is up to the individual debugger extensions ti implement their side of it. My JS Debugger extension "Javascript Debugger (Nightly)" apparently does not implement it.  I am not sure which JS Debugger extension do implement it, nr how to find out other than installing them one by one (no thank-you).

Comment: @RBarryYoung Yes, thanks for your understanding. but my VS code are already latest version right now, but it seem not work at JavaScript.

Comment: @JamesPeng Yeah, me too.  :-(

Comment: The specific line means you can add a break point to the line, and debug it. If your adding the break point, but the debuggers not hitting it, then its something in your code. The yellow are allows you to set break points in a line when theres more than one entity on a single line that can have a break point set to it. So the debugger breaks when it hits the entity.

Comment: You set the break points on that line your pointing at, from what the picture shows, it should stop at the breakpoint(S) <- plural, as you have two breakpoints set on **Line #23**. Once you pass that line, its executed, and you cannot go backwards and have it execute becuase that code doesn't exist in the form that it did when it was executing.